# How to convert from Multisite to Domain Access? Need single Administration for all sites

Tags: 7, multi-sites, subsites

I have existing drupal 6.26 with 5 multisite subdomains, on one database. I want to create single administration for all 5 subdomains using [Domain Access](https://drupal.org/project/domain) module.

Ideally, most of the administrative tasks should be implemented in a single change. Things like content types, meta tag and post settings, taxonomy. the structure of pages under site building, site configuration, user permissions. All the things that make a site consistent in its look and function.

Files Structure: MAIN website: sites/all/default/settings.php SubDomain1 : sites/one.EXAMPLE.com/settings.php SubDomain2 : sites/two.EXAMPLE.com/settings.php SubDomain2 : sites/three.EXAMPLE.com/settings.php

DB: Single DB for MAIN and all subdomains.

Tables for EXAMPLE.com doesn't have any $db_prefix where all subdomains tables have their $db_prefixes like bellow:

one_nodes, two_nodes,three_nodes ...

one_node_access, two_node_access, two_node_access ...

one_node_type, two_node_type, three_node_type ...

After enabling the [Domain Access](https://drupal.org/project/domain) module I navigate to : http://EXAMPLE.com/admin/build/domain

1 - I found only the MAIN domain in (Domain List) tab, instead of all my existing subdomains.

2 - How/Where can I set a single administration to achieve the above mention task?

Comment: *how* did you create the existing 5 subdomains? Do you have multisite or separate installs on them? Or no Drupal at all and they are only domain names not used yet?

Comment: I have Drupal multisite subdomains with single DB.